# copy rows depending on column value

Tags: vba, excel

I want to copy certain columns from one excel file to another. Basically I want to make a search for "occupation", followed by a IF sentence that copies only that column ("occupation"), if the salary is above 100,000. Of course in the real file I do not know which column contains "Occupation".

```
Sub FindMelData() 
Dim MEL As Workbook 
Dim FinalRow As Integer 
Dim i As Integer 
Sheets("MEL-Input").Activate 
Sheets("MEL-Input").Range("A1:BJ3000").ClearContents 
iName = Cells(1, 1) 
iOccup = Cells(1, 2) 
iSalery = Cells(, 3) 

Set MEL = Workbook.Open("path") 
area = MEL.Sheets("MEL").Range("A1").Value 
FinalRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 
For i = 2 To FinalRow 
   If Cells(i, 3) > 100000 Then 
      MEL.Sheets("MEL").Range(Cells(i, 2)).Copy 
      ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MEL-Input").Range("A3000").End(xlUp).O‌​ffset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats 
      End If 
      Next i 
End Sub
```

So what I want shown on my new file is:

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

I have no good ideas on how to start this, so this far I have just made a loop that finds the column no in the file I want to copy from. This works, but if the columns are to change, then my script will not wor anymore.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6Xb6.png)

Comment: Could you post your code through editing this question? Please show us what you tried to do.

Comment: Hi, I uploaded what I've done so far. Very new to vba scripting, so it is not much to go from.

Comment: You should post your code as text with formatting.

Comment: Sub FindMelData()
Dim MEL As Workbook
Di FinalRow As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Sheets("MEL-Input").Activate
Sheets("MEL-Input").Range("A1:BJ3000").ClearContents
iName = Cells(1, 1)
iOccup = Cells(1, 2)
iSalery = Cells(, 3)
Set MEL = Workbook.Open("path")
area = MEL.Sheets("MEL").Range("A1").Value
FinalRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To FinalRow
 If Cells(i, 3) > 100000 Then
 MEL.Sheets("MEL").Range(Cells(i, 2)).Copy
 ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MEL-Input").Range("A3000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
 End If
 Next i
End Sub

Comment: Thanks for clarifying your question